# Moving a vector of unique_ptrs bug

Tags: c++

I've always used `std::move` to move a `std::vector` into an empty one in member initialization lists like this:

```
class Bar{};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>&& t_values)
        : m_Values{ std::move(t_values) }
    {
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> m_Values{};
};
```

I thought that the `std::move` in the constructor would clear the `t_values` vector, but recently I've discovered a bug that does not clear the `t_values` `vector` and causes unexpected behaviour e.g. destroying the `vector`s elements before they should be (`std::swap` would fix this issue). Is it not required by the standard for the moved vector to be empty?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A move results in a "valid but unspecified state":

```
Moved-from state of library types                     [lib.types.movedfrom]

Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from.
Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless
otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid
but unspecified state.
```

A moved-from vector can certainly be empty, that would be "valid". But nothing in the C++ standard requires that. In the case of a moved-from vector of `std::unique_ptr`s, it would also be "valid" if the moved-from vector remains non-empty, but now has some indeterminate number of default-constructed `std::unique_ptr`s (the moved-from vector's size can remain the same, or may be different). The original `std::unique_ptr`s are now in the moved-to vector, and the moved-from vector has some default-constructed `std::unique_ptr`s. No rules are broken. The moved-from vector is in a "valid" state.

For various practical reasons, it's extremely unlikely for a moved-from vector in any typical C++ library implementation to behave this way, in this case. That's very unlikely. But it would be valid, if it were the case, provided that the overall state is still valid. It would not be valid for both the moved-from and the moved-to vector of `std::unique_ptr`s to end up with `std::unique_ptr`s to the same objects.

If you're observing spurious, or extra, object construction or destruction, it must be due to undefined behavior of some other source. There's nothing wrong with the shown code. If there's undefined behavior, it must be in code that's not shown.

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is not happening in this snippet, I just cannot seem to recreate the problem outside my project, thank you, I will try to find the real cause of the bug.

Comment: I agree. It is extremely implausible that an implementation chooses to leave a vector that was moved into a vector constructor in a state other than capacity = size = 0.

Comment: Some standard C++ library classes have additional guarantees beyond valid-but-unspecified.  `std::vector` has such a guarantee (and `std::unique_ptr` and a few others).  Howard Hinnant pointed point that for one's *own* user-defined types, they can have whatever post-condition guarantee you want (but I just go with valid-but-unspecified for mine, so I don't have to think about it too hard).

Comment: I found the mistake, it was a dumb copy+paste mistake, the member variable was not of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>` but of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>&&` ... thank you guys though